# Email matching regex taking long time in java but evaluates quickly in java script

Tags: java, javascript, regex

The following email validation code in Java takes forever to give an answer.

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class abc {
    private static Pattern validEmailPattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*"
            + "@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$");

    public static void validateEmailPattern(String emailId) {
        Matcher emailMatcher = validEmailPattern.matcher(emailId);
        if (emailMatcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println("MATCHED");
        } else {
            System.out.println("UN- MATCHED");
        }

    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String emailId = "tmaloneysdkjhrfsdlfhsldhflsdhflshlfhsf+NA5@amazonsdafshkjhfksefskdhkjksdhhfskjhfjhkhkffakhfkahskfhkahsdkjhf840h0ry0wy430ohwrghkcghkvlbhj.com";
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        validateEmailPattern(emailId);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(end-start);
    }
}
```

while the counter part in javascript gives a good performance:

```
var email = "tmaloneysdkjhrfsdlfhsldhflsdhflshlfhsf+NA5@amazonsdafshkjhfksefskdhkjksdhhfskjhfjhkhkffakhfkahskfhkahsdkjhf840h0ry0wy430ohwrghkcghkvlbhj.com";

//Email is stored as a request preference whose max length is 200. Although email can be of 256 characters,
if (email.length <= 200) {
    var validEmailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?\^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?\^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$/;

    if(validEmailRegex.test(email)) {
        console.log("Matched");
    } else {
        console.log("Not Matched");
    }
}
```

Here is a fiddle for the same: http://jsfiddle.net/amandeepautam/HKhw8/548/
Note that the email string in question is less than 200 characters in length.

What can be the reasons for this? What can be a suggested optimization for the java code?
An optimization I can think of is (not implemented) to break the regex into small independent regex and evaluate domain, start middle part independently.

Comment: Why don't you just use the javamail API? It has a pretty solid implementation of recognizing email addresses; better than what any regex can do

Comment: I'd give it a run of at least 100 calls and draw an average time. Benchmarking a single call is really unfair ;)

Comment: @ptrk single call itself takes minutes to evaluate against the javascript call which is probably in milliseconds.

Comment: That's what I mean - the single call is the first call. See how much it takes for subsequent ones (within one app run). There might be costs of class loading.

Comment: "Takes minutes" isn't realistic.  You have some other problem, perhaps a busy system.  On my cruddy old lap top, your code takes just barely over one millisecond.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam (Sorry about editing my post, I saw the "takes minutes" comment after I posted.)

Answer (score 2):

To match an email in java use the regex:

```
"(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])"
```

---

```
public static boolean isEmail(String mail)
{
    return Pattern.compile("(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])").matcher(mail).find();
}
```

---

I have looked at your regex to find the catastrophic backracking:
In your Java Regex you have not escaped the dot at the beginning of the first non capturing group and the dot at the end of the second non capturing group. If you escape them the regex will work much faster without catastrophic backtracking.

In your JavaScript regex you have escaped the dots correct.

Your corrected java regex is:

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$"
```

Comment: improved the performance significantly. May I know the reason why and could you please explain the changes as well?

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam Your regex is slower because you have catastrophic backtracking - Your sample email needs more  than 1 million matching attemps. - The other regex needs 33

Comment: I was reading catastrophic backtracking and it suggest that we can have atomic groups. Would this be a good idea: `^(?>[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)(?>(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+))*@(?>(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\\.)+)(?>[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?)$` . In this I have put atomic grouping for all sub-parts of email like domain etc.

Answer (score 0):

The probable issue is **[catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)** in your regular expression.

It is quite difficult to get email regex right.

Answer (score 0):

Backtracking problems.

I'd try this one from the  html5 specs.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#valid-e-mail-address

```
 # "^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$"

 ^ 
 [a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+ 
 @
 [a-zA-Z0-9] 
 (?:
      [a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61} 
      [a-zA-Z0-9] 
 )?
 (?:
      \. 
      [a-zA-Z0-9] 
      (?:
           [a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61} 
           [a-zA-Z0-9] 
      )?
 )*
 $
```